# UIPageViewController with more than one indicator dot lit

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have a UITabBarController, leading to two small scrollable booklets. Each booklet has its own ViewController which uses UIPageViewController to present the content pages. This mostly works correctly, showing the appropriate number of PageControl indicator dots with these indicating the pages correctly.

However, when I am, say, on page 2 of Book A and then tab to Book B, the correct number of indicator dots appears for Book B but two indicator dots are highlighted. Moving back and forth between the books can also result in more than two indicators showing as highlighted.

I would appreciate any help resolving this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay. My bad!

I was instantiating the pageViewController more than once.